# Adding a column in dataframes based on similar columns in them

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get an output where I wish to add column `d` in d1 and d2 where a b c are same (like groupby).

For example

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]],columns=['a','b','c','d'])

d2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]],columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

then I'd like to get an output as

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  8
1  2  3  4  5
```

Merging the two data frames and adding the resultant column `d` where a b c are same.

`d1.add(d2)` or `radd` gives me an aggregate of all columns

The solution should be a DataFrame which can be added again to another similarly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first:

```
print (d2.set_index(['a','b','c'])
         .add(d1.set_index(['a','b','c']), fill_value=0)
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index())

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  8
1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: I wanted it to be added in a recursive loop. The column names have been a bit off. a b c appear as inner columns and shape appears to be (2,1) . So if I add a the resultant to a third DataFrame it is not able to find the keys a b c.

Comment: I wasn't doing reset index I guess. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.concat([d1, d2])
df.drop_duplicates()

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  5
```